# Add a row for each date in year with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to add for my data 365/366 rows so for each date in some year (etc.2014)...

I have:

```
//something like for each date in this year add row with data...
     $STH1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO workhours (ID_radnika,ime,datum,user_id) values ($orderID,:1,HOW TO FOREACH DATE,:2)");  
          $STH1->bindParam(':1', $_POST['ime']);
          $STH1->bindParam(':2', $user_id);

          $STH1->execute();
```

So this is a simple quesry I have. Now I need for my data which I know (ID_radnika,ime,user_id) add 365 rows but only to change datum (date)

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another parameter:

```
$STH1 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO workhours (ID_radnika,ime,datum,user_id) values ($orderID,:ime,:date,:uid)");
```

Execute with the parameters changed:

```
    $max_days = ((((($year%4)==0)&&((($year%100)!=0)||(($year%400)==0))))?366:365);
    $startOfYear = strtotime(date('Y-01-01 0:00:00'));
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max_days; $i++) {
        $STH1->execute(array(
            ':ime' => $_POST['ime'],
            ':uid' => $user_id,
            ':date' => $startOfYear + $i*86400,
   ));
```

You could do that with a single query if you like. Then you need to do:

```
$values      = array();
$startOfYear = strtotime(date('Y-01-01 0:00:00'));
$max_days = ((((($year%4)==0)&&((($year%100)!=0)||(($year%400)==0))))?366:365);
for ($i = 0; $i < $max_days; $i++) {
    $values[] = "($orderID, :ime, ".($startOfYear + $i * 86400).", :uid)";
}
$stm = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO workhours (ID_radnika,ime,datum,user_id) values ".implode(',', $values));
$stm->execute(array(':ime' => $_POST['ime'], ':uid' => $user_id));
```

Comment: I assume he wanted to do it in MySQL, and the solution you posted is also wasting resources.

Comment: but where here is date? i need loop from 01.01.2014 to 31.12.2014

Comment: @Andrew I added the date, assuming you save timestamps

Comment: @colburton the foreach was in MySQL not in PHP, but still it is wasting resources. What you can do simply in SQL is better to do in SQL instead of php.

Comment: @tekan what ressources? this is a prepared statement, no ressources are wasted here!

Comment: @colburton You execute 365/6 queries, that generate plus 364/5 times the overhead between php and MySQL.

Comment: nice, but please write full answer

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with full answer, but I've updated my anser

Comment: Added leap year support.

Comment: as you can see: http://i.imgur.com/56NFk5b.png the time I add into database with this code is WRONG

Comment: @Andrew What do you mean, wrong? Looks good to me. These are timestamps as expected.

Comment: for first row I need to get: 1388530800000 => 2014.01.01

Comment: but I get: 1420066800 which is when I cnvert into date: 1.1.1970 !

Comment: @Andrew the screen does show the last row, not the first

Comment: ok but then when I transform miliseconds to date I need to get 31.12.2014 !

Comment: These are not miliseconds. These are seconds!

Comment: can I transform seconds to date when I add it?

Comment: In php you can use date('FORMAT', SECONDS); to get any date format you like.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(IN id INT, In ime VARchar(20),In userid INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE start_date DATE default '2020-06-16';
DECLARE end_date DATE default '2021-06-16';
DECLARE DiffDate int default 1;
SELECT DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date) AS DiffDate
into DiffDate;
while DiffDate>0 do
  INSERT INTO workhours(ID_radnika,ime,datum,user_id)
  values (id,ime,start_date,userid);
    select  DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    into start_date;
    SELECT DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date) AS DiffDate
    into DiffDate;
end while;
END
```

Comment: this is procedure.you can also use in php

Comment: @Andrew and it is also fast

Comment: @AmitDubey Do not try, he still needs php... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHILE` in MySQL as described here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html

```
DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 365;
WHILE v > 0 DO
    ... insert to ...
    SET v = v - 1;
END WHILE;
```

You can find the needed date manipulation functions also in the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

The one which you need is: `MAKEDATE(year, dayofyear)`

Comment: but where here is date? so in need loop from 01.01.2014 to 31.12.2014

Comment: I provided you a way to do `foreach` in MySQL. Put the `INSERT` query in the place of `... insert to ...`.

Comment: @Andrew added date functions.

Comment: how to add date function, please write full answer

Comment: @Andrew You have all the ingredients to make it. This website is not about solving the problem instead of you, but giving you hints and steps along what you can solve it and learn from it.

Comment: You can execute MySQL queries in php like you did it in your question also. Sorry that I avoided writing obvious things.. (what I assumed you know from your question).